# DSum returning number of rows instead of total value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

I have the following code attached to a text box in a form:

```
=DSum("[subform].Form![POINTS]","ATTENDANCE","[subform].Form![EMPLOYEE NO] = [EMPLOYEE NO]")
```

Ideally this would yield the total amount of points accrued by the employee we are currently searching for. However, what I am getting is the total sum of rows in my table.

Does anybody have any idea of how I could get the total sum of the values instead of the number of rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the total from a subform, and your subform in in sync with the main one, it will be much more efficient to procede this way:

1. create txtTotalPoints textbox `= sum(Points)` in the footer of your subform
2. refer to that control from your main form: txtMainResult `=subform!form!txtTotalPoints`
3. Hide txtTotalPoints (or the footer itself)

That will generally be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the Domain functions such as DSum, DLookup, DCount etc. are used to lookup and return values from a table. The first argument is the field, the second the table, and the third is the criteria or WHERE statement that makes sure you get the correct set of records. Your first argument refers to a form's field. I think this is incorrect. Your first item in your WHERE statement is also a form field. I this this is also incorrect. You need to try something like this instead:

```
=DSum("POINTS","ATTENDANCE","[EMPLOYEE NO] = " & [subform].Form![EMPLOYEE NO])
```